# How to concat two utf8 string in erlang?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, erlang

I have two variable as below:

```
A = <<"سعید"/utf8>>,
B = <<"حیدری"/utf8>>,
```

how can i concat `A` and `B` ?

```
C = <<A/utf8, B/utf8>>.
```

line above returns `exception error: bad argument`

Comment: You may find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600642/how-do-i-concatenate-two-binaries-in-erlang

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`utf8` is just encoding. It is binary as any other binary:

```
1> A = <<"سعید"/utf8>>,
1> B = <<"حیدری"/utf8>>,
1> C = <<A/bytes, B/bytes>>.
<<216,179,216,185,219,140,216,175,216,173,219,140,216,175,
  216,177,219,140>>
2> io:put_chars([C, $\n]).
سعیدحیدری
ok
```

P.S.: The result is shown reversed because of web browser behavior. It is shown in correct order in the console.